# how to set classpath for a Java program on hadoop file system

Tags: java, hadoop, classpath

I am trying to figure out how to set class path that reference to HDFS? I cannot find any reference.

```
 java -cp "how to reference to HDFS?" com.MyProgram
```

If i cannot reference to hadoop file system, then i have to copy all the referenced third party libs/jars somewhere under $HADOOP_HOME on each hadoop machine...but i wanna avoid this by putting files to hadoop file system. Is this possible?

Example hadoop command line for the program to run (my expectation is like this, maybe i am wrong):

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -input inputfileDir -output outputfileDir -mapper /home/nanshi/myprog.java -reducer NONE -file /home/nanshi/myprog.java
```

However, within the command line above, how do i added java classpath? like
    -cp "/home/nanshi/wiki/Lucene/lib/lucene-core-3.6.0.jar:/home/nanshi/Lucene/bin"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add to your classpath a HDFS path. The java executable wouldn't be able to interpret something like :

```
hdfs://path/to/your/file
```

But adding third party libraries to the classpath of each task needing those libraries can be done using the *-libjars* option. This means you need to have a so called driver class (implementing **Tool**) which sets up and starts your job and use the -libjars option on the command line when running that driver class. 
The Tool, in turn, uses GenericParser to parse your command line arguments (including -libjars) and with the help of the JobClient will do all the necessary work to send your lib to all the machines needing them and to set them on the classpath of those machines.

Besides that, in order to run a MR job you should use the hadoop script located in the bin/ directory of your distribution.

Here is an example (using a jar containing your job and the driver class):

```
 hadoop jar jarfilename.jar DriverClassInTheJar 
 -libjars comma-separated-list-of-libs <input> <output>
```

Comment: Thanks Razvan! I will need to use $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar to map the input files. Then have my own java program to process the input streams (file contents). I am still confused about how to write a driver class. Can you please point me to some documentation or example? thanks a lot!

Comment: that library should be on all the machines in the cluster running hadoop. You don't have to send it from the client.

Comment: that library should be on all the machines in the cluster running hadoop. You don't have to send it from the client.
See here: slide 27 http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/75/Developing%20applications%20for%20Apache%20Hadoop%20Presentation.pdf

Comment: I think i am still confused...modified my question by adding more info about what i need...hmm.let me re-read your answer...still trying to figure out.

Comment: A jar is a standard way of packaging any application so I don't see what would be the problem with placing your class(classes in a jar).

Comment: Razvan, yeah, you right. I am working on trying it out by following your suggestion right now. Will let u know. Sorry that i am new to all these, so that i need some time to figure out everything.

Comment: but you don't have to do that. you can send the external jars using the -libjars

Comment: I am confused again...I basically really need an example about this.

Answer (score 11):

What I suppose you are trying to do is include third party libraries in your distributed program. There are many options you can do.

Option 1) Easiest option that I find is to put all the jars in $HADOOP_HOME/lib (eg /usr/local/hadoop-0.22.0/lib) directory on all nodes and restart your jobtracker and tasktracker.

Option 2) Use libjars option  command for this is 
    hadoop jar -libjars comma_seperated_jars

Option 3) Include the jars in lib directory of the jar. You will have to do that while creating your jar.

Option 4) Install all the jars in your computer and include their location in class path.

Option 5) You can try by putting those jars in distributed cache.

Comment: hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -libjars lucene-core-3.6.0.jar,hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar,concept.jar -input mydata_in -output mydata_out -mapper "java mylucene.conceptRunner" -reducer NONE

Comment: The above is the command that runs finally. Added to this post for anyone else as a reference. Thanks a lot for your help, Animesh. Thanks Razvan too for your patient help!

Comment: Once the program runs on hadoop, i got an exception as "failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit" that i am still investigating...

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I have a question please. Can libjars reference hdfs jar files (because I want to avoid putting the jars in every node local file system)? If no how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the jar path as
-libjars hdfs://namenode/path_to_jar
,I have used this with Hive .