# How can I get a custom Charset to load in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, classloader

Background: I have a data supplier that is providing XML documents with a bogus character encoding. It is not a valid encoding name (but it is essentially ISO 8859-1.) I cannot get this supplier to change the format.

Attempting to parse these XML documents using a DOM parser results in an `UnsupportedEncodingException` being thrown. This is probably normal behavior, and I can work around it by writing a `Charset` that wraps the ISO-8859-1 character encoding and by writing a `CharsetProvider` to support it. When I add this provider to `META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider`, everything works well and my Charset is used to read the XML with no additional coding.

Here is the problem that I cannot solve: **how to get Hadoop to recognize this Charset and CharsetProvider.** I am running a Hadoop job to read sequence files from HDFS, where each record is one of the above-described XML documents. I cannot get my Charset to be recognized and used by the DOM parser.  The system is running Java 1.6, Hadoop 0.20.2, and the XML parser is the internal Xerces parser built into Java 1.6.

Some additional details:

I can force the CharsetProvider to load manually in my code, by doing the following (using the "context class loader"), but I still cannot instantiate the Charset, and the XML parsing fails:

```js
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
ServiceLoader<CharsetProvider> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(CharsetProvider.class, cl);
for (CharsetProvider i : serviceLoader) {
    LOG.info("CharsetProvider[1]: " + i);
}
```

Looking at the list of available Charsets, I see my encoding is present when I run as a standalone Java app, but not when I run inside Hadoop.

```js
Set<String> charsetNames = Charset.availableCharsets().keySet();
for (String name : charsetNames) {
    LOG.info("Charset: " + name);
}
```

The following fails under Hadoop, but works otherwise:

```js
Charset cs = Charset.forName(MY_CHARSET_NAME);
```

I suspect there is some magic configuration I need to tell Hadoop to load my CharsetProvider, but I cannot find out how.

Comment: create a jar of those charset and place it in $HADOOP_HOME/lib folder, then restart your hadoop job-tracker and task tracker, it should work then.

Comment: @AnimeshJha thanks for the suggestion. I don't have root on this cluster, so I cannot try that. Is there a way to do it without writing to a system directory?

Comment: oh, use libjar command, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696563/how-to-set-classpath-for-a-java-program-on-hadoop-file-system/11698561#11698561

Comment: At this point, I've tried everything I can think of. I have created a separate jar containing the charset and the CharsetProvider and loaded it with the -libjar option. I can see the classes (and create an instance of the charset manually), but the XML parser still cannot find it, and I cannot instantiate it via `Charset.forName()`. I am going to be forced to use the ugly workaround of modifying the encoding="..." line when I read it in before passing it to the parser :-( Thanks for the help.